# How to automatically expand snippets without opening suggestion window in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've installed VS Code extension named [dsznajder.es7-react-js-snippets](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dsznajder.es7-react-js-snippets)  to quickly type boilerplate ES7 code.

So when I type **imd** a quick suggestion shows up
[image]

and then by pressing **Tab** this snippet expands
[image]

I want to get the following behavior:

1. Disable **Quick Suggestion** so it will not be showed up automatically
2. Create keyboard shortcut which, after I typed **imd**, and called shortcut will expand snippet automatically (without showing suggestion / autocompletion windows and needing to navigate to snippet)

How would I do that?

Answer (score 4):

Add the following to your [user settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings):

```
{
  "editor.tabCompletion": true,
  "editor.quickSuggestions": {
    "other": false,
    "comments": false,
    "strings": false
  }
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work. I couldn't find how `"editor.tabCompletion": true` change vs code behaviour, but **Tab** after imd just adds space.

Comment: Are you sure you added the settings correctly? Open user settings and type "editor.tabCompletion" into the search bar. The result will have a commented description above the setting, describing what the setting does. Hover over the setting, click the edit icon and select `true`. Do the same for "editor.quickSuggestions" — click edit button, copy to user settings and change the `other` property to `false`.

Comment: Ahhhh, thank you!!! So annoying waiting ~2 seconds for suggestions popup ! :-)

Comment: Goodness I've been looking for ages THANK YOU, there's a new settings called "onlySnippets" as of today

Answer (score 0):

See:

> // Control whether an active snippet prevents quick suggestions.

```
   "editor.suggest.snippetsPreventQuickSuggestions": false,
```

so suggestions do not intrude while completing a snippet.